# How do I interact with the hackage API using curl?

Tags: haskell, curl, hackage

There are sparsely documented methods [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/api). [This page](https://hackage.haskell.org/) just mentions there's an API, and links to the [hackage-security](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hackage-security) library which 5min poking around doesn't help me figure out how to form an http request to the (which?) server

The following just get me a stub html file:

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/json"   hackage.org/package/aeson/
$ curl -H "Accept: application/json"   hackage.org/api/package/aeson/
```

old related: [Does Hackage have an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467478/does-hackage-have-an-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the base URL wrong. It's `https://hackage.haskell.org/`.

```bash
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson
```

yields the output

```json
{"0.1.0.0":"normal","0.10.0.0":"deprecated","0.11.0.0":"normal","0.11.1.0":"normal","0.11.1.1":"normal","0.11.1.2":"normal","0.11.1.3":"normal","0.11.1.4":"normal","0.11.2.0":"normal","0.11.2.1":"normal","0.11.3.0":"normal","0.2.0.0":"normal","0.3.0.0":"normal","0.3.1.0":"normal","0.3.1.1":"normal","0.3.2.0":"normal","0.3.2.1":"normal","0.3.2.10":"normal","0.3.2.11":"normal","0.3.2.12":"normal","0.3.2.13":"normal","0.3.2.14":"normal","0.3.2.2":"normal","0.3.2.3":"normal","0.3.2.4":"normal","0.3.2.5":"normal","0.3.2.6":"normal","0.3.2.7":"normal","0.3.2.8":"normal","0.3.2.9":"normal","0.4.0.0":"normal","0.4.0.1":"normal","0.5.0.0":"normal","0.6.0.0":"normal","0.6.0.1":"normal","0.6.0.2":"normal","0.6.1.0":"normal","0.6.2.0":"normal","0.6.2.1":"normal","0.7.0.0":"deprecated","0.7.0.1":"deprecated","0.7.0.2":"deprecated","0.7.0.3":"deprecated","0.7.0.4":"normal","0.7.0.5":"deprecated","0.7.0.6":"normal","0.8.0.0":"deprecated","0.8.0.1":"deprecated","0.8.0.2":"normal","0.8.1.0":"normal","0.8.1.1":"normal","0.9.0.0":"normal","0.9.0.1":"normal","1.0.0.0":"normal","1.0.1.0":"normal","1.0.2.0":"normal","1.0.2.1":"normal","1.1.0.0":"normal","1.1.1.0":"normal","1.1.2.0":"normal","1.2.0.0":"normal","1.2.1.0":"normal","1.2.2.0":"normal","1.2.3.0":"normal","1.2.4.0":"normal","1.3.0.0":"normal","1.3.1.0":"normal","1.3.1.1":"normal","1.4.0.0":"normal","1.4.1.0":"normal","1.4.2.0":"normal","1.4.3.0":"normal","1.4.4.0":"normal","1.4.5.0":"normal","1.4.6.0":"normal","1.4.7.0":"normal","1.4.7.1":"normal","1.5.0.0":"normal","1.5.1.0":"normal","1.5.2.0":"normal","1.5.3.0":"normal","1.5.4.0":"normal","1.5.4.1":"normal","1.5.5.0":"normal","1.5.5.1":"normal","1.5.6.0":"normal","2.0.0.0":"normal","2.0.1.0":"normal","2.0.2.0":"normal","2.0.3.0":"normal"}
```